# Returning unknown size array to Java with SWIG wrapper

Tags: java, c++, swig

I have written a small data type that stores data in a `char` array. Here is a basic definition in the header file:

```
class SimpleBuffer {
public:
    ...
    const char* getData();
    int getSize();

private:
    char* data;
};
```

I would like for `getData()` to return a copy of its representation as a `byte[]` in Java. My typemaps are shown below:

```
    %typemap(jstype) const char* SimpleBuffer::getData "byte[]"
    %typemap(jtype) const char* SimpleBuffer::getData "byte[]"
    %typemap(jni) const char* SimpleBuffer::getData "jbyteArray"
    %typemap(out) const char* SimpleBuffer::getData {
            $result = JCALL1(NewByteArray, jenv, arg1->getSize());
            JCALL4(SetByteArrayRegion, jenv, $result, 0, arg1->getSize(), (const jbyte*)arg1->getData());
    }
```

While this compiles, I had to reference the `arg1` variable, which is the `SimpleBuffer` pointer that is passed into the JNI function. Is there a better way to do this? Does SWIG define a `$` variable to access the class passed into the JNI function (i.e., `arg1`)?

Thanks for the help!